# CSS hide elements behind logo

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where I need to remove/hide a line behind my transparent logo:

[image]

The white line needs to be beside the logo, but it should not be shown behind. - And no, I will not add a black background..

Code:

```
<div style="position: absolute;margin-top: 74px;margin-left: 4%;width: 90%;height: 2px;background-color: #FFF;"></div>
<span style="font-size:81px;margin-top: 14px;padding: 0px 0px 0px 43%;position: fixed;">LOGO</span>
```

- Span will become a transparent image, this is just for testing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the Line-On-Sides Headers CSS Trick.

Something like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.fancy {
  line-height: 0.10;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 81px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.fancy span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.fancy span:before,
.fancy span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
.fancy span:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.fancy span:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fancy"><span class="fancy">LOGO</span>
</div>
```

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a transparent background, I think the only way is to duplicate the line div and divide it in two, one left and one right, I don't know the dimensions you need, but you should have something like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute;margin-top: 74px;margin-left: 4%;width: 30%;height: 2px;background-color: #FFF;"></div>
<span style="font-size:81px;margin-top: 14px;padding: 0px 0px 0px 43%;position: fixed;">LOGO</span>
<div style="position: absolute;margin-top: 74px;margin-left: 60%;width: 30%;height: 2px;background-color: #FFF;"></div>
```

Hard to say the correct margins without knowing where they are contained, you should post the entire HTML if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

Few things...

**1.** Your methods of positioning in the code snippet you included are, quite frankly, awful. I'd clean this up and not using things like `padding: 43%` to position your elements - make sure you have a sturdy foundation before you go building a house on it! I'd suggest checking out some resources in regards to positioning elements using CSS - given that you've provided just a 2-line snippet, I can't exactly go into what proper methods would be in your case.

**2.**

> And no, I will not add a black background..

You're acknowledging the simplest working answer, yet you don't want to use it...? Why not? Do you mean you don't want to apply a background to the *image*? You can just add it to the span using `background-color: black;`

**3.** Again, I don't approve of position the elements in this manner, however using your snippet (and applying the 43% on the `margin` instead of `padding`), you can achieve this: https://jsfiddle.net/dgat2q34/

For additional space between the line and the text, you'd then use `padding` on the `span`.

**EDIT:** [Kaiwen Huang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4491274/kaiwen-huang) brings up a good point - if you didn't want to use specifically black as I've included in my example, you can change the span's background to `background-color: inherit;` instead.

Comment: Perhaps "background-color: inherit" on the image or span would solve your issue if you do not want to explicitly define the color.

Answer (score 0):

I would absolutely position the elements in a container and then arrange them with z-index to ensure they stack in the correct order. I have created a JSfiddle with a quick example of how to acheive this:

https://jsfiddle.net/bL0dfkvq/

The key here is the z-index on the text is:

```
z-index:10;
```

The z-index on the hr line is:

```
z-index:5;
```

Comment: The issue is not related to `z-index`. His image is already in front of his line. The problem is that the image is transparent.

Comment: Quite right. Reading that back to myself I can see what the users requirements were. I thought the OP wanted to ensure the line appeared behind the text.

Comment: Understood, simple mistake. That being said, I included an answer - the solution would be just to add `background-color: black` to the span, however OP has specifically stated "No, I will not add a black background" in his question -_-

Comment: Im trying to hack together a solution that uses (the not entirely supported) clip or mask features of CSS:

https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

If you could get it so that the mask element overlays the HR and applies to that, that should achieve the desired output. Although if this was me, unless there was a good reason, I would have just gone with :before and :after tags as per NickyTheWrench's answer and got on with my next task.

Answer (score 0):

You might test this code:

```html
<div id="#bg" style="border:1px solid ; position:relative; background-color:black; display: inline-block"><hr id="line" style="border: 1px solid #ffffff; position:absolute; width:98%; top:50%; z-index: 0;margin:0"><div id="#container" style="border:1px solid ;position:relative; background-color:none; display: inline-block"><div style="margin:0px 35px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#333333;  font-size: 80px">LOGO</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set your logo to have a higher `z-index:` than the line.

Z-index is basically:

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Comment: His logo is already in front of the line. The logo is an image with transparency, thus the line still displays between the letters etc.

Comment: Right. I've overlooked that the logo is transparent. Probably the easiest solution would be background inherit